# min rows multiplication by the max rows

Tags: r, matrix

I have two matrices as follows in R:

```
M<-matrix(c(1,4,1,3,1,4,2,3,1,2,1,2),3)

1    3    2    2
4    1    3    1
1    4    1    2

N<-matrix(c(1,1,2,2,3,4,-2,2,1,4,3,-1),3)

1    2   -2    4
1    3    2    3
2    4    1   -1
```

I want to find a vector which is a matrix 1*3 and each of its elements is the multiplication of min element of each row of M by the max element of the corresponding row of N (for example, the first element of the vector is the min element of the first row of matrix M, which is 1, multiply by the max element of the first row of matrix N, which is 4, and so the first element of the vector is 1*4 which is 4). 
The final answer is: (1*4, 1*3,1*4)=(4,3,4)

To find this vector (or matrix) I have written the below code:

```
c(min(M[1,])*max(N[1,]),min(M[2,])*max(N[2,]),min(M[3,])*max(N[3,]))
```

But it is so long. could anyone write a shorter (or simpler, or easier) code?

Answer (score 5):

```
apply(M, 1, min) * apply(N, 1, max)
```

Comment: Thank you Jan,
I have a question. What does the number 1 exactly inside the apply function? I do not know why you have put 1.

Comment: or with `matrixStats`: `rowMins(M) * rowMaxs(N)`

Comment: See `?apply` - it determines the dimension to cycle through. If you want the equivalent task done across columns instead of rows, you change 1 to 2.

Comment: Jan, I think 1 is for the row and 2 is for the column. right?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to tackle this, and maybe also the most readable, is to use apply (as already suggested by @Jan):
`apply(M, 1, min) * apply(N, 1, max)`

However, if you have a lot of data, the `apply` approach - which loops through all the data - can be slow.  A faster way is to use built-in *vectorized* functions to perform fast operations on all the rows together.
The R `max.col(m)` function returns the index of the column with the highest value in each row of a matrix `m`.  There isn't a `min.col(m)` function, but you can obviously get the same result as by using `max.col(-m)`.
So, the *vectorized* approach is:

```
M_min_of_each_row=M[cbind(seq_len(nrow(M)),max.col(-M))]
N_max_of_each_row=N[cbind(seq_len(nrow(N)),max.col(N))]
answer=M*N
```

How much faster is this for a *big* matrix?  We can use `microbenchmark` to test:

```
using_apply=function(M,N) apply(M,1,min)*apply(N,1,max)
using_maxcol=function(M,N) M[cbind(seq_len(nrow(M)),max.col(-M))]*N[cbind(seq_len(nrow(N)),max.col(N))]
library(microbenchmark)
M=matrix(sample(1:100,40000,replace=T),ncol=4);N=matrix(sample(1:100,40000,replace=T),ncol=4)
microbenchmark(using_apply(M,N),using_maxcol(M,N))
# Unit: milliseconds
#               expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#  using_apply(M, N) 25.319694 28.411979 31.762766 30.829093 33.789692 71.893174   100
# using_maxcol(M, N)  1.608357  1.876968  2.117926  2.042053  2.270023  4.858531   100

# check that the results are the same:
all(using_apply(M,N)==using_maxcol(M,N))
# [1] TRUE
```

So: the *vectorized* approach is about 15x faster.  But, of course, you might consider that the `apply` approach is good enough, and that it's more-concise and (arguably) more-readable...